# select input option selected

Tags: html, forms

i have select field with multiple options:

```
<option value="lotr">Lord of the Rings</option>
<option value="harry_potter">Harry Potter</option>
```

when it is submitted value "lotr" or "harry_potter" is sent, depended on users choice. 
However from time to time i need to set options in back end, including previously chosen option. So i make those options look like this:

```
<option selected="lotr">Lord of the Rings</option>
<option value="harry_potter">Harry Potter</option>
```

Form is displayed correctly, i can see "Lord of the Rings" in the input, but when i try to submit it, also there is "Lord of the rings" in the params. Point is i need it to be "lotr". I have no idea what i do wrong, maybe there is another way of making selected option?

Comment: Can you post your js code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set selected="true" and value="lotr" as below

```
<option selected="true" value="lotr">Lord of the Rings</option>
```

Comment: correct, i just figured it out second after submitting this question:)

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<option value="lotr" selected >Lord of the Rings</option>
```